# routes with default value acts differently on its type

Tags: flask

below is part of my code

```py
@app.route('/users/', defaults={'user_id': 1})
@app.route('/users/<int:user_id>')
```

if I go to `/users/1` then, it redirects me to `/users/`.

but if I remove int: part, like below

```py
@app.route('/users/', defaults={'user_id': 1})
@app.route('/users/<user_id>')
```

It doesn't redirect me and path stays at `/users/1`.
This is confusing me.
What is going on and what is the best practice?

here's screen shot of my console outputs:
[image]

as you can see, if I go to `/users/1` flask redirects me to `/users/`

Comment: Both work for me. What version of Flask are you using? I'm using the latest version (2.0.1)

Comment: @BasvanderLinden Sorry for late reply. my versions are $ flask --version Python 3.9.5 Flask 2.0.1 Werkzeug 2.0.1 Im also using latest versions. I added some screenshots to clarify my problems so plz check Thank you.